# Efficiently re-ordering a ranked collection in Django

Tags: django, sorting, linked-list, unique-constraint, m2m

Let's say I want to have collections of books and within each collection the books sorted by a unique ranking.

One simple implementation may look like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
​
​
class Collection(models.Model):
    # e.g. adventure, classic, fairy tale, ....
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
​
​
class Membership(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
​
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('rank',)
        # 1. Can't have same rank twice in a given collection
        # 2. Don't want duplicate books in same collection
        unique_together = (('collection', 'rank'), ('collection', 'book'))
```

This works OK, but the main problem is if I want to re-order the collection in an new, different way whilst respecting uniqueness constraints
E.g. Let's say some collection has

1. War and Peace
2. Crime and Punishment
3. The Gambler
4. For Whom The Bell Tolls
5. Moby Dick

And we want to re-order to

1. Moby Dick
2. For Whom The Bell Tolls
3. Moby Dick
4. Crime and Punishment
5. The Gambler

How can we do that?  Simply trying to re-assign ranks like Moby Dick = 1, would fail, because there'd already be a Membership with rank 1 ("War and Peace") and the unique constraints would forbid it. I'd
have to somehow change all the ranks simultaneously perhaps?

I've ended up simply deleting all `Memberships` of the collection every time I want to re-order, and re-creating them with the new ranks, but this isn't very efficient.
​
Reading around I'm wondering if a linked list approach help me out of this mess? If so how would this work exactly with the above example?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to get a random order queryset you can do `.order_by('?')`

Comment: No I'm referring to updating the ranks to some new ordering. Not reading the existing objects in a given order (or random order)